# Clone Oracle Express Edition 11g R2

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-xe

I have installed Oracle XE 11g R2 on my machine. I ran few scripts which does the setup by creating schemas, procedures for our application. Now I want to clone this database so that other people by using the cloned dbf file can see the base schema on their respective machine and work on their individual requirement on top of that.

Now it has 6 dbf files

```
CONTROL.DBF    
SYSAUX.DBF   
SYSTEM.DBF   
TEMP.DBF   
UNDO.DBF   
USER.DBF
```

Can i just give them the files or I need to create server parameter file (`SPFILE`) or Control file. What about the `REDO` logs.
I have very little knowledge in Database administration. Please suggest. I understand that it is not Enterprise Edition so all things might not supported but assuming cloning process is similar for XE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing content as it is not valid here

Answer (score 4):

While it is possible to restore a database using the data files, I strongly suspect that is not what you're really after.  If you're not an experienced DBA, the number of possible issues you'll encounter trying to restore a backup on a different machine and then creating an appropriate database instance are rather large.

More likely, what you really want to do is generate a full export of your database.  The other people that need your application would then install Oracle and import the export that you generated.

The simplest possible approach would be at a command line to

```
exp / as sysdba full=y file=myDump.dmp
```

You would then send `myDump.dmp` to the other users who would import that into their own database

```
imp / as sysdba full=y file=myDump.dmp
```

This will only be a logical backup of your database.  It will not include things like the parameters that the database has been set to use so other users may be configured to use more (or less) memory or to have a different file layout or even a slightly different version of Oracle.  But it does not sound like you need that degree of cloning.  If you have a large amount of data, using the DataPump version of the export and import utilities would be more efficient.  My guess from the fact that you haven't even created a new tablespace is that you don't have enough data for this to be a concern.

For more information, consult the Oracle documentation on the [export and import utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm).

Comment: On windows received `LRM-00108: invalid positional parameter value 'as'`. Quoting the connect helps e.g.:  `exp '/ as sysdba' full=y file=myDump.dmp`